# Delete in Tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a login system in Tkinter using Python.
So the way I want to do it is by asking the user for a username. When they click next the username field should dissapear and a new field named password should appear instead. So when I tried to do this I get an error:

```
e1 is not defined in line 27, in button
```

I understand that the variable has not been declared yet, but it should have done it, as I have put everything in a main() function.

This is my code

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

root = Tk()
root.title("Loginsystem")
root.geometry("300x200")

def main():
    def username_page():
        Label(root, text="Username").place(x=10, y=10)
        e1 = Entry(root)
        e1.place(x=140, y=10)
        uname = e1.get()

    def password_page():
        Label(root, text="Password").place(x=10, y=40)
        e2 = Entry(root)
        e2.place(x=140, y=40)
        e2.config(show="*")

    def button():
        #Hide the username input field
        e1.delete()
        #Show the password input field
        password_page()


    username_page()

    Button(root, text="Next", command=button, height = 3, width = 35, background = "blue", foreground = "white").place(x=10, y=100)

    root.mainloop()


main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very easy way to do it, without moving lines here and there, i.e. **declaring `e1` as Global**.

Also, hiding doesn't mean *deleting*, use `e1.place_forget()` to hide the widget

Here is the code which works:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Loginsystem")
root.geometry("300x200")

def username_page():
    global e1, myLabel
    myLabel = Label(root, text="Username")
    myLabel.place(x=10, y=10)
    e1 = Entry(root)
    e1.place(x=140, y=10)
    uname = e1.get()

def password_page():
    Label(root, text="Password").place(x=10, y=40)
    e2 = Entry(root)
    e2.place(x=140, y=40)
    e2.config(show="*")


def button():
    # Hide the username input field
    e1.place_forget()
    myLabel.place_forget()
    # Show the password input field
    password_page()

def main():
    username_page()
    Button(root, text="Next", command=button, height = 3, width = 35, background = "blue", foreground = "white").place(x=10, y=100)
    root.mainloop()

main()
```

Comment: Cool! That works, but it does not delete the username text. Is there a similar way to do that?

Comment: @lukas Answer Updated to include it :)

Answer (score 2):

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

root = Tk()
root.title("Loginsystem")
root.geometry("300x200")


def main():
    e1 = Entry(root) # MOVED E1 HERE

    def username_page():
        Label(root, text="Username").place(x=10, y=10)
        e1.place(x=140, y=10)
        uname = e1.get()

    def password_page():
        Label(root, text="Password").place(x=10, y=40)
        e2 = Entry(root)
        e2.place(x=140, y=40)
        e2.config(show="*")

    def button():
        #Hide the username input field
        e1.place_forget()
        #Show the password input field
        password_page()

    username_page()
    Button(root, text="Next", command=button, height = 3, width = 35, background = "blue", foreground = "white").place(x=10, y=100)
    root.mainloop()


main()
```

`e1` was declared in the scope of the `username_page()` function, so it was only accessible in it and not outside. The fact that `username_page()` was declared inside `main()` doesn't mean `e1` was declared in the scope of your `main()`.

Also, `e1.delete()` doesn't work, I believe you want `e1.place_forget()`. When you want `e1` to be visible again, you can call `.place()` like you did in `username_page()`.

Comment: `e1.delete()` or `e1.delete(0)` is not hiding the Entry

Comment: @SamakshGupta You're right, my mistake. I'll edit it.

Comment: Uhh, I am sorry but the code says to **hide**, destroying isn't a alternative to hide. Maybe use `.place_forget()`?

Comment: @SamakshGupta Correct again, I wasn't aware of it! Thanks. I'd delete my answer to leave yours, since our programs are almost identical, but I dislike using globals in nearly every situation, so I'd rather have both up for OP to choose.

Comment: Haha, yes our answers are pretty same, but I am afraid that you answered first, so you shouldn't delete it :)